# Android DatePicker calendar's last row is cropped

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I want to display a DatePicker, that contains only a calendar, but i get this kind of bug:

[Screen with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB4Ep.png)

I found some people had this kind of problem too, but have somebody found a solution for this?

It occurs on Api > 21, most of resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that this can be easily reproduced after we set the Setting->Display->Display Size to Large. And then go to a month that needs to show 6 rows. The Google Calendar app have the same problem.

[image]

So it should be a bug in the DatePicker. The only easy solution is to change the datepicker to the spinner style.

[image]